# Pandas VLOOKUP values that do not match

Tags: pandas, excel, vlookup

For example I have two tables:

`w_results.xlsx`:

[image]

```
           Item    Type  Score
0  mashpotatoes    food     30
1        daniel  person     99
2         paper   thing     24
3          john  person    195
4          lamp   thing      5
5       jessica  person     92
6         pizza    food     42
7          meat    food      2
8         jacob  person     83
```

`w_runnable.xlsx`:

[image]

```
           Item    Type  Score    
0  mashpotatoes    food         30
1          john  person        195
2     raspberry    food         50
3        iphone   thing         75
4         boat    thing          5
5          jake  person         25
6         pizza    food         42
7          meat    food          2
8        daniel  person         99
```

How can I get a table of all values that appear on w_results 'Item' column but not in w_runnable "Item" column?
I know that using `pd.merge` is probably the way to go, but it just outputs the matches. My attempt below:

```
import pandas as pd
w_results = 'w_results.xlsx'
w_runnable = 'w_runnable.xlsx'

df_results_mylist = pd.read_excel(w_results, sheet_name='my_list')
df_runnable_mylist = pd.read_excel(w_runnable, sheet_name='my_list')

left_join = pd.merge(df_results_mylist,
                     df_runnable_mylist,
                     on = 'Item',
                     how = 'left')

print(left_join)
```

Output:

```
      Item  Type_x  Score  Type_y  Score    
0  mashpotatoes    food     30    food       30.0
1        daniel  person     99  person       99.0
2         paper   thing     24     NaN        NaN
3          john  person    195  person      195.0
4          lamp   thing      5     NaN        NaN
5       jessica  person     92     NaN        NaN
6         pizza    food     42    food       42.0
7          meat    food      2    food        2.0
8         jacob  person     83     NaN        NaN
```

The values that do not match appear as `NaN` (paper, lamp, jessica, jacob).
Don't know if there's a cleaner way to do this, so that these values appears in a separate table. Any help would be appreciated.

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: plz provide code or text of input, not image

Comment: and your desired output exactly.

Comment: I updated it, I updated desired output in images since I don't know how to get output in pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

make Item column and Type column to list in Series

```
cols = ['Item', 'Type']
df_results_mylist[cols].agg(list, axis=1)
```

result:

```
0    [mashpotatoes, food]
1        [daniel, person]
2          [paper, thing]
3          [john, person]
4           [lamp, thing]
5       [jessica, person]
6           [pizza, food]
7            [meat, food]
8         [jacob, person]
dtype: object
```

create condition using `isin` function in similar way

```
cond = df_results_mylist[cols].agg(list, axis=1).isin(df_runnable_mylist[cols].agg(list, axis=1))
```

cond :

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
6     True
7     True
8    False
dtype: bool
```

---

If it is necessary to check equality only in `Item` column, create  condition with code below instead of code above.

```
cond = df_results_mylist['Item'].isin(df_runnable_mylist['Item'].unique())
```

---

no matter how cond was made, lets do boolean indexing by `~cond`

```
df_results_mylist[~cond]
```

output:

```
    Item    Type    Score
2   paper   thing   24
4   lamp    thing   5
5   jessica person  92
8   jacob   person  83
```

Comment: Hi Panda, I'm seeing that the output here is not the one I needed. For example looking at the fist value in your table, daniel, it appears in both tables. I'm looking for values that appear in the first table `w_results`, column "Item" but not in the second table `w_runnable` column "Item"

Comment: You got the wrong output. i fix it. Just run the code and you'll see that it's correct. In fact, this is the code you can understand by reading it.